# find xml files that contain milti line pattern

Tags: xml, sed

I am trying to search a large number of xml files for files that are missing a specific tag, or where the value inside that tag is 0.

Basically, each xml file has one or more LIBRARY tags, and nested inside those is one or more SECTION tags, and inside those is one or more SHELF tags. Inside the SHELF tags there *should* be a BOOK tag with an integer value that is not zero.

I need to find the files where this BOOK value is 0 or where the BOOK is missing, but **only** in the **first** SHELF of each SECTION. So if there are multiple SECTION tags nested inside multiple LIBRARY tags, I need to check the first SHELF in each and every SECTION.

```
<LIBRARY>
    <SECTION>
        <SHELF>
            <BOOK>10000</BOOK>
        </SHELF>
    </SECTION>
</LIBRARY>
```

I am trying to write a Unix script to achieve this by searching each file in a given directory and returning a list of the files that match the pattern. I have been searching for a way to do it with sed, but I can't seem to find the solution to this particular problem. Also, the xml files are multi-line files, as shown above. Thank you guys for any help you can provide!

Comment: consider about using xpath, xml schema to do that job. if you prefer unix/linux cmdline, there are xmllint, xsltclient you could think about.

Comment: Use a xml tool for this, such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) rather than grep or sed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to check, if there exists a first shelf with no book or a 0-book:

```
exists(//LIBRARY/SECTION/SHELF[1][empty(BOOK) or BOOK = 0])
```

Or easier to read with XPath 2, check for every first shelf if it has a not 0-book:

```
not(every $shelf in //LIBRARY/SECTION/SHELF[1] satisfies $shelf/BOOK[. != 0])
```

Now you need an xml tool to apply that xpath to every file and list the files that matches.

My [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) can do that directly, printing the file name/url, if the XPath condition is true:

```
 xidel --quiet -e 'if (not(every $shelf in //LIBRARY/SECTION/SHELF[1] satisfies $shelf/BOOK[. != 0])) then $url else ""' *.xml
```

(although it might be slow if you have several thousands files, never tested it with so many)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I ended up going a different route due to time constraints (manager not so happy) and a complete lack of experience with SQL tools. But I will definitely save this for later, it looks really interesting.